# Is there a command line way of attaching VS Code from local laptop to a Kubernetes Pod/Container?

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, devcontainer

Assuming that all Kubernetes RBAC permissions are granted, and a container is running in Kubernetes.

I am trying to automate or have a *simple* startup script that will find the running container based on the Kubernetes deployment name + container name, and attach VS Code to it.

From the user interface in VS Code, the menu option is as follows:
[image]

This will attach VS Code to the target container. The container in question is also a [Dev Container](https://containers.dev/) with VS Code Server support.

---

So far, from the command line, the only options available are below (which are not helpful in discovering a way to do this)

```
Visual Studio Code 1.77.1

Usage: code [options][paths...]

To read from stdin, append '-' (e.g. 'ps aux | grep code | code -')

Options
  -d --diff <file> <file>                    Compare two files with each other.
  -m --merge <path1> <path2> <base> <result> Perform a three-way merge by providing paths for two modified versions of a file, the common origin of both modified versions and the output file to save merge results.
  -a --add <folder>                          Add folder(s) to the last active window.
  -g --goto <file:line[:character]>          Open a file at the path on the specified line and character position.
  -n --new-window                            Force to open a new window.
  -r --reuse-window                          Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.
  -w --wait                                  Wait for the files to be closed before returning.
  --locale <locale>                          The locale to use (e.g. en-US or zh-TW).
  --user-data-dir <dir>                      Specifies the directory that user data is kept in. Can be used to open multiple distinct instances of Code.
  --profile <profileName>                    Opens the provided folder or workspace with the given profile and associates the profile with the workspace. If the profile does not exist, a new empty one is created. A folder or workspace must be provided for the
                                             profile to take effect.
  -h --help                                  Print usage.

Extensions Management
  --extensions-dir <dir>              Set the root path for extensions.
  --list-extensions                   List the installed extensions.
  --show-versions                     Show versions of installed extensions, when using --list-extensions.
  --category <category>               Filters installed extensions by provided category, when using --list-extensions.
  --install-extension <ext-id | path> Installs or updates an extension. The argument is either an extension id or a path to a VSIX. The identifier of an extension is '${publisher}.${name}'. Use '--force' argument to update to latest version. To install a
                                      specific version provide '@${version}'. For example: 'vscode.csharp@1.2.3'.
  --pre-release                       Installs the pre-release version of the extension, when using --install-extension
  --uninstall-extension <ext-id>      Uninstalls an extension.
  --enable-proposed-api <ext-id>      Enables proposed API features for extensions. Can receive one or more extension IDs to enable individually.

Troubleshooting
  -v --version                    Print version.
  --verbose                       Print verbose output (implies --wait).
  --log <level>                   Log level to use. Default is 'info'. Allowed values are 'critical', 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug', 'trace', 'off'. You can also configure the log level of an extension by passing extension id and log level in the following
                                  format: '${publisher}.${name}:${logLevel}'. For example: 'vscode.csharp:trace'. Can receive one or more such entries.
  -s --status                     Print process usage and diagnostics information.
  --prof-startup                  Run CPU profiler during startup.
  --disable-extensions            Disable all installed extensions. This option is not persisted and is effective only when the command opens a new window.
  --disable-extension <ext-id>    Disable the provided extension. This option is not persisted and is effective only when the command opens a new window.
  --sync <on | off>               Turn sync on or off.
  --inspect-extensions <port>     Allow debugging and profiling of extensions. Check the developer tools for the connection URI.
  --inspect-brk-extensions <port> Allow debugging and profiling of extensions with the extension host being paused after start. Check the developer tools for the connection URI.
  --disable-gpu                   Disable GPU hardware acceleration.
  --max-memory <memory>           Max memory size for a window (in Mbytes).
  --telemetry                     Shows all telemetry events which VS code collects.

Subcommands
  tunnel       Make the current machine accessible from vscode.dev or other machines through a secure tunnel
```

Comment: And you try to do what? Containers are not made for developing inside of them. Develop & test local, deploy your app via container.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? looking to debug locally with vs code ?

Comment: I edited the question in response to your comments. We are using [Dev Containers](https://containers.dev/) which allow for remote software workspace connected from local VS Code instance.